# HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, httpclient

Hi I am using HTTPClient gem and I have a problem; I use it for user signup. While running user name and password are inserted to my database but it waits long and return to me

```
HTTP Client::ReceiveTimeout Error in User Controller#signup execution expired.
```

how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your http connection or remote connection is not stable. 
Whenever i have that situation, i use timeout and retry for few times.
The following code will execute your code for 10 seconds, and if not finished it will timeout and retry. If retry fails for many times, it will fail eventually.

```
def timeout_and_retry
  retries = 0
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) { yield }
  rescue Timeout::Error
    raise if (self.retries += 1) > 3
    retry
  end
end

timeout_and_retry do
   # http client get code goes here
end
```

Comment: I have been used Timeout::timeout(10000) :)

Comment: Beautiful. Works a charm when Exchanger timeouts on a big inbox. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Use for receive_timeout error;

```
client = HTTPClient.new
client.receive_timeout = 10000    # setting receivetimeout for HTTPClient!
```

Comment: you can also set `send_timeout = 0` and `receive_timeout = 0` not to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you get a HTTP:ReceiveTimeOutError , it means the request has been sent and it has done waiting for a particular time and since no response, within the time , it expires and you get this error.

Always specify more time so that it waits longer for response.